# Conflicting register allocation in GCC x86_64 asm. Lifetime ignored

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I have a function containing a small assembly block. The assembly for this function compiled by GCC is incorrect since it assigns the same register to two different variables. This is the function source:

```
void *ptr;
uint64_t foo(uint64_t arg1) {
  register uint64_t tmp;
  asm ("lea TARGET(%%rip), %[tmp];"
       "shl  $4, %[arg1];"
       "sub  %[arg1], %[tmp];"
       "movq %[tmp], %[ptr];"
      : [ptr] "+m" (ptr), [tmp] "=r" (tmp)
      : [arg1] "r" (arg1)
      :);

  asm ("TARGET:;");
}
```

I use the constraint "+m" for the global `ptr` since I write to it, and it is should be in memory. The constraint for `tmp` is "=r" since its only being written to. The constaint for the input `arg1` is merely "r". This might be important.

The SSA pseudo-code for the assembly block is:

```
tmp_0 = something
arg1_1 = arg1_0 << 4
tmp_1 = tmp_0 - arg_1
*ptr_0 = tmp_1
```

The compiled assembly for this function at optimization `O0` is

```
00000000000005fa <foo>:
 5fa:   55                      push   %rbp
 5fb:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 5fe:   48 89 7d f8             mov    %rdi,-0x8(%rbp)       # Storing arg1 to stack (optimization level O0)
 602:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax       # arg1_0 is assigned register rax
 606:   48 8d 05 0e 00 00 00    lea    0xe(%rip),%rax        # 61b <TARGET>, tmp_0 is ALSO assigned rax
 60d:   48 c1 e0 04             shl    $0x4,%rax             # arg1_0 is used, its lifetime ends
 611:   48 29 c0                sub    %rax,%rax             # subtracting two vars both assigned the same register
 614:   48 89 05 fd 09 20 00    mov    %rax,0x2009fd(%rip)   # 201018 <ptr>, store to global

000000000000061b <TARGET>:
 61b:   90                      nop
 61c:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 61d:   c3                      retq
```

Inspecting the assembly, we see that in address 0x602, the register `rax` is assigned to the SSA register `arg1_0` whose lifetime is till the instruction 0x60d. Meanwhile, the instruction at address 0x606 ALSO assigns the register `rax` to the SSA register `tmp_0`. It seems that a physical register was assigned to another SSA register during its lifetime.

System information:

- x86_64 CPU
- gcc version 7.4.0
- Ubuntu 18.04.3

My questions:

- Why does GCC create such an assembly output?
- Are my constraints to the assembly inputs and outputs correct? If not, why?
- Is this a GCC bug?

Comment: The [manual says](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html): _"Use the ‘&’ constraint modifier (see Modifiers) on all output operands that must not overlap an input. Otherwise, GCC may allocate the output operand in the same register as an unrelated input operand, on the assumption that the assembler code consumes its inputs before producing outputs. This assumption may be false if the assembler code actually consists of more than one instruction. "_

Comment: This seems to be perfectly relevant. This implies that GCC is not using the sort of lifetime analysis that compilers generally use. Is there a real challenge to doing this with inline assembly?

Comment: @TSG The compiler does not inspect your inline assembly for it cannot and must not.  You have to do this analysis and present it as constraints to your assembly code.  That's why I usually advice to avoid inline assembly if possible.

Comment: Aha! Makes sense, though we are relying on it for a lot of work, including register allocation.

Comment: @TSG Yeah, but inline assembly is basically “manual mode” concerning lifetime analysis and instruction selection.

Comment: `movq TARGET(%%rip), %[tmp];` You know that's a load of the machine-code bytes of the function epilogue, right?  Did you want a RIP-relative LEA to get a pointer to store in something you're calling a pointer?  I have no idea what you're doing here.  You definitely can't safely jump to `TARGET:`.  If you want that, use a C label and `asm goto`.

Comment: I realised that the appropriate opcode is `lea` not `mov` since I do want to jump to TARGET eventually. I've updated my code accordingly.

Comment: Didn't see your reply, don't forget to @TSG people.  (You get notified because we're commenting under your answer.  Other people don't.)  Anyway, perhaps you're looking for GNU C computed goto / taking the address of a C label. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html.  You can use the label address as an input for an asm statement, or just cast to `uintptr_t` and avoid inline asm entirely. The advantage here is that the compiler knows there's a possible jump target there, and you can use `asm goto` so your jump can optimize safely.

Comment: [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) *does not parse the assembler instructions themselves and does not know what they mean or even whether they are valid assembler input.*  I believe other compilers (clang?) might do things differently, but for gcc, the efficiently and functionality of the asm block lives and dies by the constraints.  Obscure details like `&` are part of the reason I suggest people [don't use inline asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm). It's hard to get right, easy to get wrong, and daunting for others to maintain.

Comment: "don't use inline asm. It's hard to get right, easy to get wrong, and daunting for others to maintain. – David Wohlferd Dec 18 '19". Going on my wall. @DavidWohlferd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, thanks @Jester for the perfect comment which answers this question. To quote:

> The [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) says: "Use the ‘&’ constraint modifier (see Modifiers) on all output operands that must not overlap an input. Otherwise, GCC may allocate the output operand in the same register as an unrelated input operand, on the assumption that the assembler code consumes its inputs before producing outputs. This assumption may be false if the assembler code actually consists of more than one instruction. "

In short, my inline assembly does not agree with `gcc`s assumption that inputs be consumed before outputs are written to. In fact, `gcc` provides the appropriate, if somewhat obscure, constraint modifier (`&`) to express this.

The fix:

```
-       : [ptr] "+m" (ptr), [tmp] "=r" (tmp)
+       : [ptr] "+m" (ptr), [tmp] "=&r" (tmp)
```

The fixed assembly output:

```
00000000000005fa <foo>:
 5fa:   55                      push   %rbp
 5fb:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 5fe:   48 89 7d f8             mov    %rdi,-0x8(%rbp)
 602:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
 606:   48 8d 15 0e 00 00 00    lea    0xe(%rip),%rdx        # 61b <TARGET>
 60d:   48 c1 e0 04             shl    $0x4,%rax
 611:   48 29 c2                sub    %rax,%rdx
 614:   48 89 15 fd 09 20 00    mov    %rdx,0x2009fd(%rip)        # 201018 <ptr>

000000000000061b <TARGET>:
 61b:   90                      nop
 61c:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 61d:   c3                      retq
```

Comment: There’s a another problem with the constraints in this inline assembly code that this answer doesn’t mention. `arg1` is listed only as a input in the constraints, but it is modified by the assembly code.

Comment: @prl, you might be correct. It is, however, totally irrelevant in the rest of the code, so I'll let it lie and not further complicate this QA